# How do I link a page in a template?

Tags: theming

If there is a basic page with the route '/about', how can I link it in a template file?

```
<a href="{{ What goes here? }}"></a>
```

Comment: `<a href="/about"></a>`

Answer (score 2):

Let assume the page is a node whose ID is 4. You can use the following code, in a template file.

```
<a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': 4}) }}">About us</a>"
```

Comment: Is there no way to specify using a path based on the URL alias? Such as '/about'?

Comment: @crayden What if a month from now someone decides to change it to /about-us? What do you think will happen if the alias changes?

Comment: @crayden in the case above, `path()` will automatically get the URL, the alias if there is one, based on the node id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the path function to call specific routes

```
<a href="{{ path('user.register') }}">My link</a>
```

Or of course, you can do it the old-fashioned way

```
<a href="/about">My link</a>
```